# Ranking by number of points with php

Tags: php, html

I have a question. I'm currently working on a ranking list webprogram for a shooting club made with php and html.

Now I'm at the point, where I want to print out the ranking table with the results from my sql database. The ranking table is showing a rank, personal informations and the results. The results where sort by the scored points.

My problem now is, that I dont know how to make an automatic rank per person. The only thing I managed to do is this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBKgo.png)

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <div>
    

                <h3 style='color:green; font-weight: 700;'> <?php echo "Rangliste $infos" ?> </h3>
                <a class='btn btn-default' href='?page=rangliste'>Zurück</a>
                <a class='btn btn-default' href='?page=rangliste_veteranencup'> <span class=''></span> Veteranen Cup</a>
                <a class='btn btn-default' href='?page=rangliste_dianacup'><span class=''></span>Diana Cup</a>
                <a class='btn btn-default'  href='?page=rangliste_gäste'><span class=''></span>Gäste Cup</a>


    
                <style> 
                
                table {

                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    width: 90%;
                    color: black;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    text-align: left;
                }

                div {

                    margin-left: 50px;
    
                }

            

                th {

                    border: 1px solid black;
                    background-color: #D3DFDD;
                }

                td {

                    text-align: center;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    background-color: white;
                }

                

                .outlined {

                    border: 2px solid black;

                }
                
                </style>
                <p></p>
             <table>
             <colgroup>
                <col>
                <col>
                <col>
                <col>
                <col>
                <col>
                <col>
                <col>
                <col>
                <col class='outlined'>
                <col span='3'>
    </colgroup>
                <tr>
                    <th scope='col'>Rang</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Vorname</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Nachname</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Jahrgang</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Wohnort</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Total Reh</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Total Gams</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Total Klapphas</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Total Rollhas</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Gesamttotal</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Tiefschuss Reh</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Tiefschuss Gams</th>
                </tr>
    <?php 

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "art");
    if ($conn-> connect_error) {

        die("Connection failed" . $conn-> connect_error);

    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT schuetze.vorname, schuetze.nachname, schuetze.jahrgang, schuetze.ort,
        resultate.vmTotalReh, resultate.vmTotalGams, resultate.vmTotalKlapphas, resultate.vmTotalRollhas, resultate.vmTotal, resultate.vmTiefschussReh, resultate.vmTiefschussGams
        FROM schuetze
        JOIN resultate ON schuetze.id = resultate.schuetzeID
        WHERE resultate.anlassID = ? ORDER BY resultate.vmTotal DESC, resultate.vmTotalKlapphas DESC, resultate.vmTotalRollhas DESC, resultate.vmTotalReh DESC, resultate.vmTotalGams DESC, resultate.vmTiefschussReh DESC, resultate.vmTiefschussGams DESC, schuetze.jahrgang DESC";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $res_anlassID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

        while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {

                echo "</td><td>"/* . $rang . "</td><td>" */. $row['vorname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['nachname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['jahrgang'] . "</td><td>" . $row['ort'] . "</td><td>"  . $row['vmTotalReh'] . "</td><td>" . $row['vmTotalGams'] . "</td><td>" . $row['vmTotalKlapphas'] . "</td><td>" . $row['vmTotalRollhas'] . "</td><td>" . $row['vmTotal'] . "</td><td>" . $row['vmTiefschussReh'] . "</td><td>" . $row['vmTiefschussGams'] . "</td></tr>";
                
        }
 
    echo "</table>";
    

    $conn-> close();
    ?>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Compare the scored points of the current user, with those of the previous one. If they differ … then you need to add 1 to you current rank value.

Comment: Use `RANK()` in SQL